# ruby on rails index action not loading by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, indexing, action

The Controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
get "search/index"
```

from `rake routes`

```
search_index GET    /search/index(.:format)        search#index
```

when i try to go to `http://localhost:3000/search` i get a 404 page error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your routes should be:

```
 search_index GET    /search(.:format)              search#index
```

change your `get "search/index"` to:

```
resources :search, :only => [:index]
```